# Construct color octet

Tags: group-theory, quantum-chromodynamics, gluons

I'm reading about color octet, considering $r= \begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}$ $b= \begin{bmatrix}0 \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}$ $g= \begin{bmatrix}0 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}$ and $\lambda_{i}$ [Gell-Mann matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gell-Mann_matrices).

> I really do not understand how to construct the following basis for gluons. 
>   Someone could do some explicit calculation.

$ |1\rangle = (r\otimes\bar{b}+b\otimes\bar{r})/\sqrt{2}= \lambda_{1}/ \sqrt{2}$

$|2\rangle = -i(r\otimes\bar{b}-b\otimes\bar{r})/\sqrt{2}= \lambda_{2}/ \sqrt{2}$

$|3\rangle =(r\otimes\bar{r}-b\otimes\bar{b})/\sqrt{2}= \lambda_{3}/ \sqrt{2}$

$|4\rangle = (r\otimes\bar{g}+g\otimes\bar{r})/\sqrt{2} = \lambda_{4}/ \sqrt{2}$

$|5\rangle = -i(r\otimes\bar{g}-g\otimes\bar{r})/\sqrt{2}= \lambda_{5}/ \sqrt{2}$

$|6\rangle = (b \otimes\bar{g}+g\otimes\bar{b})/\sqrt{2}= \lambda_{6}/ \sqrt{2}$

$|7\rangle = -i(b\otimes\bar{g}-g\otimes\bar{b})/\sqrt{2}= \lambda_{7}/ \sqrt{2}$

$|8\rangle =(r\otimes\bar{r}+b\otimes\bar{b}-2g\otimes\bar{g})/\sqrt{6}= \lambda_{8}/ \sqrt{2}$

Answer (score 1):

First of all note that the tensor product of two matrices $A,B$ with $A:=(a_{ij})$ is defined as:
$$A\otimes B=
\begin{bmatrix}
a_{11}B & a_{12} B &\cdots \\
a_{21}B & a_{22} B &\cdots \\
\vdots & \vdots &\ddots \\
\end{bmatrix}.$$

If we view a vector as a special case of a matrix, then that means that any fermion with a colour index is actually the tensor product $u_i(p)=e_i\otimes u(p)$, where $e_i=r,g,b$ is the *colour vector*.

We can decompose a matrix into the tensor product of a row vector times a column vector (as opposed to the other way around, which would give you the Euclidean scalar product of both vectors): $A=v^T\otimes w$, where $v,w$ are themselves column vectors.

So the idea to write, e.g. $\lambda_1=r\otimes\bar{b}+b\otimes\bar{r}$, is to just write the Gell-Mann matrix in terms of the base vectors of colour and anticolour space. If you do the calculation for $r\otimes\bar{b}+b\otimes\bar{r}$ by hand, you will see that you end up exactly with the Gell-Mann matrix $\lambda_1$. The same goes for the other Gell-Mann matrices.

One can now say that those Gell-Mann matrices are not just mathematical matrices but that each of them is a *colour-anticolour charge transfer operator* since in the QCD Lagrangian the gluon-quark interaction terms couple the quark fields to the gluon fields via these Gell-Mann matrices.